# ajaxSubmitButton not working on linux server

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, yii

Below is an ajaxSubmitButton that in working on a mac but not on a linux server.  On the linux server Error Console shows this error: SyntaxError: missing } after property list

```
<?php
     echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton(
        '',          
        array('/modelA/action'), 
        array(
            'type'=>'POST',
            'success' => 'js:function(){window.location="/modelB/action"}',
        ),
        array(
            'id'=>'button',
        )
    ); 
?>
```

When I copy the error from Firebug or Error Console I get this:

SyntaxError: missing } after property list
https://www.mysite.com/assets/95062282/jquery.ba-bbq.js
Line 853

and Firebug looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Please post the resulting Javascript. If I understand correctly, this error shows in your browsers javascript error console?

Comment: updated question, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: kind of, but I think I have enough information to help you out, see my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the 'js:' part in your code (before function) then it should work

So it will look like this:

```
<?php
     echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton(
        '',          
        array('/modelA/action'), 
        array(
            'type'=>'POST',
            'success' => 'function(){window.location="/modelB/action"}',
        ),
        array(
            'id'=>'button',
        )
    ); 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
array(
        'id'=>'button',
                      ^---
```

dangling commas are the source of many JS problems.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the code shown above is PHP, not javascript

Comment: True, but the op's error message is not a standard php one. php never complains about missing `}`, it'll just spit out an "unexpected whatever_comes_next" instead.

Comment: Removed comma but problem still exists

Comment: @MarcB correct, that's why I asked OP to post the resulting javascript as I suspect that's where the error is